# AllOf Hamcrest matcher with Maven

Tags: unit-testing, maven, hamcrest

Running

```
assertThat(collection, allOf(hasItems(i1, i2, i3), hasSize(3)));
```

from Eclipse (Run as -> Junit) everything works fine, but when I execute Maven test (`mvn clean test`) it fails during `test-compile` phase with the following explanation

```
[ERROR] The method allOf(Matcher<? super T>, Matcher<? super T>) in the type AllOf<T> is not applicable for the arguments (Matcher<Iterable<Song>>, Matcher<Collection<? extends Object>>)
```

The dependencies are

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
  <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
  <version>4.10</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Stefano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify type arguments for the methods `hasItems` and `hasSize`. Automatic type inference by the compiler doesn't work in your case. To specify the type arguments, you must not use the static imported methods, but qualify them with their declaring class - `Matchers.<Song>hasItems(i1,i2,i3)` for example.